# Unable to guess MIME type in my laravel file

Tags: php, laravel

my localhost website that I am working on was working fine, however, once I added the following block of code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
       'title' => 'required|max:255',
       'category' => 'required',
       'colors' => 'required',
       'price' => 'required',
       'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
]);
```

I had this error

> Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you
> enabled the php_fileinfo extension?).

I also added the following code "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" in xampp php.ini file because it was not in my php.ini because I thought it will work but still the error is being showed again.

Comment: You've added the line to the ini file, but is the extension actually installed?

Comment: Hi Andy can you please let me know how can I check ?

Comment: Create a php file with <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> and that'll list all your available extensions, usually if it's a part of it it'll just be commented out in the ini file, if you've had to add it to the ini file I would guess that it isn't installed inside your Xampp instance. If, however, it is installed, just make sure you restart apache after changing the ini file to ensure it loads the extension

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not installed in php.ini and  get this error when I write composer install : "Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update." shall I uninstall and reinstall php ?

Comment: xampp on windows configured with `extension=fileinfo` instead and the `dll` file is located in `xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\ext`. may we know your xampp version?

Comment: @BagusTesa xampp v3.3.0

Comment: and my php version is PHP 8.1.11

Comment: When composer gives you that error, you just need to run composer update instead of composer install

Comment: @AndyHolmes I tried, however I still get the same error unable to guess the MIME type